# VAR MODEL: Error in solve.default(Sigma) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number

Tags: r, regression, time-series, least-squares, vector-autoregression

I am using R `vars` package to implement VAR model in a multivariate time series model. I tried to run:

`VAR(foo_ts, p = 6)`

but I was getting this error message:

`Error in solve.default(Sigma) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 0`

[foo_ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tj7csIPjNR1FN7y7_0bisE8QdSXO9OcF/view?usp=sharing) is a time series data.

I have tried to adapt examples in [stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371249/matrices-system-that-is-computationally-singular-versus-exactly-singular)  and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451664/system-is-computationally-singular-error) but have not been successful in running the VAR model. I have successfully run the VAR model on other datasets but not on [foo_ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tj7csIPjNR1FN7y7_0bisE8QdSXO9OcF/view?usp=sharing). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the error message online?

Comment: Yes. I have looked at the message online. The answer I saw is that "It means your design matrix is not invertible". But then, I do not have clue on how to adapt the solution when using R vars package.

Comment: No package will help you if the problem lies in the data. You need to reconsider the variables you have; some of them form a linear combination equal to a constant. To solve the problem, you could get rid of the variable(s) causing that.

Comment: @RichardHardy, my guess would be severe overfitting rather than multicollinearity here.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, yes, that must be the case. I did not inspect the data and forgot to consider this possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Your time series is too short to fit that many parameters. Recall that, in a VAR(p) model
\begin{equation*}
x_t = d + A_1 x_{t-1} + A_2 x_{t-2} + \dots + A_p x_{t-p} + \epsilon_t,
\end{equation*}
each parameter matrix $A_i$ will have dimension $k\times k$, where $k$ is the number of parameters. Estimation simply procedes by OLS to each equation of the VAR model. That means you will have $1+k\times p$ parameters per equation (assuming $d$ for the deterministic component is just a constant). In your case, $p=6$ and there are $k=8$ variables (although two of these appear to be identically zero and hence not very useful).

Hence, you fit 49 coefficients for each equation, but only appear to have $n=21$ observations. As is well-known, the $X'X$ matrix of the OLS estimator will not be invertible when $n$ is smaller than the number of regressors.

Comment: I am getting a similar error message after running `(VAR_reduced <- VAR(VAR_data_1, p = 1, type = "both"))
summary(VAR_reduced)` but with a condition number just above zero. I am only using 3 variables but have 135 observations, so I should not be overfitting. Any idea what may cause that? Maybe I should add that I only get the error message after `summary`

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example, perhaps as a new question?

Comment: I have but on stack overflow I assumed it would fit better there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077895/r-irfs-in-a-svar-model-cant-display-specified-model