# What is a consequence of an ill-conditioned Hessian matrix?

Tags: hessian

In [this publication](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.8580) I found an explanation of the Hessian matrix, along with what it means for it to be ill-conditioned. In the paper, there is this link given between the error surface and the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix:

> The curvature of the error surface is given by the eigenvalues
>   $\lambda_i$ of the Hessian matrix.

so it gives me a bit of hint as to why it might be important to care if it is poorly conditioned. But I'm not quite there yet, I have troubles seeing the consequences of an ill-conditioned Hessian.

So my question is: could you give me some intuitive understanding why should we care? In particular, in what models and how it can cause problems?

Comment: one reason is that optimization algorithms often use the inverse of the hessian ( or an estimate of it ) to maximize the likelihood and if it's ill-conditioned,  inverting it will be problematic. there are probably many other good reasons but that's one.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7308 for a detailed, worked, well-discussed example of the problems that arise. (It's necessary to read several of the answers there, not just one.)  The meaning of "only" computation-related is dubious, given that in the statistical contexts where such Hessians arise there is no such thing as a datum given with perfect mathematical accuracy and thus there is no such thing as a perfect idealized mathematical solution.

Comment: Briefly, the problem arises because some parameters have huge curvature while some have smaller curvature. Learning rate has to be shrunk to compensate for the high curvature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easiest understood when considering solving the linear problem,
$$
Ax = b
$$
where $b$ and $A$ are the problem data, and $x$ the parameters we are trying to estimate. In practice you have errors in $b$ which propagate through $A$. How?
Assume we have only errors in the measurements, $b$, and denote $\delta b$ and $\delta x$ the errors in the measurements and estimatation, respectively.
Because of linearity,
$$
\delta b = A \delta x
$$
In order to see how the measurements errors are magnified by the matrix $A$, you can calculate,
$$
\frac{||\delta x ||}{||x||}/\frac{||\delta b ||}{||b||}
$$
We have that this number is bounded by the condition number of $A$,
$$
cond(A) = \frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{n}}
$$
where $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{n}$ are the biggest and smallest eigenvalue of $A$, resp. Hence, the bigger the condition number, the higher the magnification of errors.

Here, a low condition number corresponds to directions where the gradient is small, which leads to oscillations and slow convergence.

This issue has motivated a lot of research for the optimization of neural networks (as you already point out), which has led to the development of techniques like momentum (see [On the importance of initialization and momentum in deep learning](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Efritz/absps/momentum.pdf)) and early stopping. This [blog](https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/) entry provides a very nice description of this topic.

Comment: @JW I edited the answer to fix this (and a minor typo in text), you could do it as well ;-)

Comment: @JW Wait, the problem is the eigenvalue ratio is only applicable to normal matrices (for real matrices that means being either orthogonal, symmetric, or skew-symmetric, which obviously fails for Hessians in general), and even then it requires taking the absolute value

Answer (score 2):

Many optimization methods, such as [Newton's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization), require the computation of the inverse of the Hessian.

The conditioning of a matrix $H$ is usually defined as the ratio between the largest and smallest singular values,
$$
\kappa(H)=\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_n}.
$$
If this number is large, that is, $\sigma_n$ is small with respect to $\|H\|$, the matrix is said to be ill-conditioned.

Now, consider the singular value decomposition of $H=U\Sigma V^T$. The inverse, provided $H$ is non-singular, can be computed as $H^{-1}=V\Sigma^+U^T$, where 
$$
\Sigma^+_{ij}=\begin{cases}1/\Sigma_{ij} &\mbox{if } i=j \\ 0 & \mbox {otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
Since $\Sigma_{nn}=\sigma_n$, whenever this value is small enough, the computation of $1/\Sigma_{ij}$ might introduce significant numerical instability.

Comment: "Will introduce" may be too strong, because it's easy to supply counterexamples.  (Consider optimization problems in which the objective function is completely separable--that is, a sum of univariate functions).  A brief investigation into exactly *how* bad conditioning *might* translate to numerical instability will reveal the additional assumptions you are making.